# How to let burst of multiple requests wait for first to complete (distributed)

Tags: go, kubernetes, redis, queue, message-queue

I have server that performs relatively expensive cpu operations with network requests and scraping, so I use a cache to optimize performance but also to prevent the overhead of a burst of requests with same item from all going I create a "waiting room" that takes the first request and once first is done the rest receive the response. This works fine when running one instance. But if I wanted to scale this to a cluster of 3 nodes, how would I solve this?

```
cached, err := exists(item)
handleErr(err)
if cached == true {
    cachedReport := getCachedRecord(item)
    fmt.Println("found in cache, sending")
    w.Write(cachedReport)
} 
else {
    fmt.Println("got request for ", item)
    if group, ok := bmap[item]; ok {
        fmt.Println("joining group for " + item)
        member := group.Join()
        val := member.Recv()

        if b, ok := val.([]byte); ok {
            fmt.Println("received from waitng, sending")
            elapsed := time.Since(start)
            log.Printf("Request for %s took %s", ticker, elapsed)
            w.Write(b)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a use case for [Redis](https://redis.io/) or something similar. Caching results for use across multiple instances of a program is best done with a cache like Redis that might be hosted in the same cluster but exists as a separate running program.

Comment: Thanks.. I am currently using redis, and looking into redis cluster... The main issue is handling the burst of initial similar requests, In load balanced cluster different nodes will pick up the requests..  how to only take first and let the rest wait until the scraping is done and result cached. I've handled this is one program but trying to figure out how to do in a distributed manner

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for redis pub/sub then. The first instance to encounter the request can create a subscription for the given item, start processing, and post the result when it's ready. The requests to follow would check to see if there is a channel for the given item and if so, subscribe to it for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a great use case for a third-party queuing/messaging mechanism/project:

- [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)
- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- [NATS](https://nats.io/)
- [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/)
- [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)
- Etc

Cloud vendors also have their offerings:

- [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)
- [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/)
- [Google Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)
- [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/)
- Etc